# aggregating results of multiple threads

Tags: java

I've a test app which runs a few thousand tests. The way it works is, for each input no or more results are generated. These results are then compared and the result written out. Currently there are multiple threads which split the input, so instead of one thread doing 10.000 test, there are x threads. The problem is, each thread is doing all the steps (read the input, generate, compare and write out the results). Some of the steps are (sometimes) long running, minutes instead of seconds.

So I want to split the work, i.e. threads A work on the first step (input to result) and split the result into multiple steps, based on some factors. Threads B then work on the comparison. A Thread C is then aggregating all the results (just some statistics) and written them out.

This Thread C is currently my "problem". To aggregate the results I thought about implementing a map, the key would be the job id and the value is just a list where all steps, of a specific job, are aggregated. That way I can then check if all steps were finished.

I wrote a little program to simulate this, which works out, but I am not sure if there isn't a better way to do it, so I was hoping for some input here.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Test().run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here the program:

```
package org.example.worker;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Test {
    public void run() throws Exception {
        //setup queues
        PriorityBlockingQueue<Result> resultQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();
        PriorityBlockingQueue<Job> jobQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();

        //setup thread count and random jobs
        int threadCnt = 4;
        Random rnd = new Random(threadCnt);

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            int num = (rnd.nextInt(0, 100) / 17) + 1;
            jobQueue.add(new Job(i, num));
        }

        //start workers
        WorkerB workerB;

        try(ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCnt)) {
            List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

            workerB = new WorkerB(0, resultQueue);
            futures.addFirst(es.submit(workerB));

            for(int i=1;i<threadCnt;i++) {
                futures.addFirst(es.submit(new WorkerA(i, jobQueue, resultQueue)));
            }

            //wait for threads to finish, be sure that the result worker is the last to finish
            for(int i=0; i<futures.size(); i++) {
                if(i == futures.size() - 1) {
                    workerB.stop();
                }

                futures.get(i).get();
            }
        }
    }

    class WorkerB implements Runnable {
        private final PriorityBlockingQueue<Result> resultQueue;
        private final int id;
        private boolean stop;

        public WorkerB(int id, PriorityBlockingQueue<Result> resultQueue) {
            this.id = id;
            this.resultQueue = resultQueue;
        }

        public void stop() {
            stop = true;
        }

        private void process(Result result) {
            System.out.println(id + ":: working on: " + result);
        }

        private void check(Map<Integer, List<Result>> results, int id) {
            List<Result> tmp = results.get(id);

            if(tmp == null || tmp.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }

            if(tmp.getFirst().total() == tmp.size()) {
                tmp.stream().sorted().forEach(this::process);

                results.remove(id);
            }
        }

        private void addOrProcess(Map<Integer, List<Result>> results, Result result) {
            if(result.total() < 2) {
                process(result);

                return;
            }

            if(!results.containsKey(result.id())) {
                results.put(result.id(), new ArrayList<>());
            }

            results.get(result.id()).add(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Map<Integer, List<Result>> results = new HashMap<>();
                Result result = resultQueue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);;

                while (!stop || result != null) {
                    if(result != null) {
                        addOrProcess(results, result);
                        check(results, result.id());
                    }

                    result = resultQueue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }

                results.keySet().forEach(k -> check(results, k));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(id + ":: " + e);
            }

            System.out.println(id + ":: shutting down");
        }
    }

    class WorkerA implements Runnable {
        private final PriorityBlockingQueue<Job> jobQueue;
        private final PriorityBlockingQueue<Result> resultQueue;
        private final int id;

        public WorkerA(int id, PriorityBlockingQueue<Job> jobQueue, PriorityBlockingQueue<Result> resultQueue) {
            this.id = id;
            this.jobQueue = jobQueue;
            this.resultQueue = resultQueue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Random rnd = new Random(id);
                Job job;

                while ((job = jobQueue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) != null) {
                    int num = (rnd.nextInt(0, 100) / 30) + 1;

                    for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {
                        resultQueue.add(new Result(job.id(), i + 1, num));

                        Thread.sleep(100L * job.amt());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(id + ":: " + e);
            }

            System.out.println(id + ":: shutting down");
        }
    }
}
```

And here the job and result class:

```
public record Job (
        int id,
        int amt
)  implements Comparable<Job> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Job job) {
        if(job == this) {
            return 0;
        }

        if(this.id < job.id) {
            return -1;
        } else if(this.id > job.id) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
public record Result(
        int id,
        int part,
        int total
) implements Comparable<Result> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Result result) {
        if(result == this) {
            return 0;
        }

        if(this.id < result.id) {
            return -1;
        } else if(this.id > result.id) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I wrote a little program to simulate the whole process and it seems to work out. While I like the (imo) straight forward way it works, I am not sure if it can't be solved in a better way.

***edit***
Forgot to add a few classes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking for suggestions on working code should be posted on sister site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I tried to write an Answer, but failed. Your logic is just too convoluted for me to follow. I suggest you post another Question with just your problem (your goal), without your proposed solution. Be very specific about what tasks (chunks of work) lead to what tasks, and how many of those tasks & sub-tasks arrive when.  …

Comment: … I suspect you are working much too hard. I am guessing that a much simpler solution could be built by using nested executor services that execute `Callable` objects rather than `Runnables` to communicate results via `Future` objects.  …

Comment: … You seem to be recreating the buffering of Runnable/Callable tasks which is the purpose of an executer service. And you seem to be recreating the collecting of results which is the purpose of `Future` objects. And you seem to be recreating the detection of an executor service completing all its tasks, which is the purpose of the try-with-resources syntax. So I bet nearly all of your code could be replaced with just a few lines, by leveraging the rich facilities offered by Java.